# How do I remove a completion in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

How do I remove a completion from Sublime Text 2?

Specifically, in a Ruby file, after the num symbol #,  hitting tab autocompletes to  # =>.

I don't need this completion, and it's really annoying when trying to write comments. How do I remove it?

Comment: Just to add, I think the `# =>`marker was a holdover from Textmate, where it was possible to use `rcodetools` via a keyboard shortcut and actually make use of the `# =>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a snippet installed by default with the Ruby package.

In order to disable it:

1. Open Sublime Text 2.
2. Select *Preferences -> Browse Packages...*
3. It will open a directory, open the directory *Ruby*
4. Rename the file `Add-'#-=-'-Marker.sublime-snippet` in `Add-'#-=-'-Marker.sublime-snippet.old`

Comment: uups - same answer in the same time ;-). As I mentioned in my answer, this is a possible way but it is invasively

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you run SublimeText2 on Mac go to Preferences > Browse Packages. In the folder Packages find the Folder Ruby. In Ruby find the file Add-'#-=-'-Marker.sublime-snippet and manipulate it.

But I strongly recommend to put the changes in a user file. I think this is Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User

See: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html

Comment: what would you put in this settings file to disable to #-= marker snippet?